# Get RoleEnvironment info from Azure Web Role Accelerator

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Is it possible to gain information about the web role from sites deployed onto the Web Role Accelerator? For example, I want to get the instance name that is being used:

```
 RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Under the covers there is nothing particularly special about the Web Role Accelerator -- it's really just a quick way to publish additional sites to a Web role that's already deployed.

`RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance` is a static property that can be called from any application, and given that `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` is true you should receive the value you're expecting.